# Grouping in order to turn row results into grouped columns

Tags: sql, db2

Currently, I'm selecting from a db2 table where each row consists of a user, sub-user (think user = manger, subuser = employee), category, daily sales and weekly goals. Here is a select all and results:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SALES_UNITS WHERE DATE >= CURRENT_DATE

  USER    |  SUB_USER        |  CATEGORY  |  DAILY  |  WEEKLY
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  123           212              RED          100        200
  123           212              BLUE         125        300
  123           212              GREEN        150        150
  123           212              BLACK        200        200
  123           212              ORANGE       250        300
  123           331              RED          125        150
  123           331              BLUE         150        200
  123           331              GREEN        300        300
  123           331              BLACK        450        150
  123           331              ORANGE       125        200
```

So I'm getting the results for each manager, basically. And this is what I expect but I'm lost on how to achieve the results I want which is to move the category daily sales and category weekly targets into the header for a file export in a script

I know I'll need to group by user, but how can I properly get the sum of each category daily sales (sum each instance of sub_user for each category) and each category weekly goal. So basically red_daily would be a sum of all daily totals where category is red, grouped at the user level

This is what I would like to achieve instead of the above result:

```
  USER  |  RED_DAILY  |  RED_WEEKLY  |  BLUE_DAILY  | BLUE_WEEKLY  | GREEN_DAILY  |  GREEN_WEEKLY  |  BLACK_DAILY  |  BLACK_WEEKLY |  ORANGE_DAILY  | ORANGE_WEEKLY
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  123           225             350           275           500             450               450             650           350               375             500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a conditional aggregation :

```
select user,
       sum(case when category = 'red' then daily else 0 end) as red_daily,
       sum(case when category = 'red' then weekly else 0 end) as red_weekly,
       sum(case when category = 'blue' then daily else 0 end) as blue_daily,
       sum(case when category = 'blue' then weekly else 0 end) as blue_weekly,
       sum(case when category = 'green' then daily else 0 end) as green_daily,
       sum(case when category = 'green' then weekly else 0 end) as green_weekly,
       sum(case when category = 'black' then daily else 0 end) as black_daily,
       sum(case when category = 'black' then weekly else 0 end) as black_weekly,
       sum(case when category = 'orange' then daily else 0 end) as orange_daily,
       sum(case when category = 'orange' then weekly else 0 end) as orange_weekly
from user_sales_unit
where date >= current_date
group by user;
```

Answer (score 1):

This just looks like a large pivot query to me:

```
SELECT
    USER,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'RED' THEN DAILY ELSE 0 END) AS RED_DAILY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'RED' THEN WEEKLY ELSE 0 END) AS RED_WEEKLY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'BLUE' THEN DAILY ELSE 0 END) AS BLUE_DAILY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'BLUE' THEN WEEKLY ELSE 0 END) AS BLUE_WEEKLY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'GREEN' THEN DAILY ELSE 0 END) AS GREEN_DAILY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'GREEN' THEN WEEKLY ELSE 0 END) AS GREEN_WEEKLY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'BLACK' THEN DAILY ELSE 0 END) AS BLACK_DAILY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'BLACK' THEN WEEKLY ELSE 0 END) AS BLACK_WEEKLY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'ORANGE' THEN DAILY ELSE 0 END) AS ORANGE_DAILY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'ORANGE' THEN WEEKLY ELSE 0 END) AS ORANGE_WEEKLY
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY USER;
```